# Getting Null Values from catelogProductinfo() function after assigning product id by foreach loop

Tags: php, json, magento, soap

```
$base='Host';
$proxy = new SoapClient($base.'/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('user123', 'user123'))
$allCategories = $proxy -> catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, 2);
$allCategories = get_object_vars($allCategories);
$i = 0;
foreach($allCategories['children'] as $k => $v ){
    $v=get_object_vars($v);
    $cat[$i]["RootCategory"] = array("Category" => $v['name']);
    $subCat = $proxy -> catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, $v['category_id']);
    $subCat = get_object_vars($subCat);
    $ii = 0;
    foreach($subCat['children'] as $k1=>$v1) {
$v1 = get_object_vars($v1);
 $cat[$i]["SubCategory"][$ii]['Subcatinfo']= array("SubCategory" =>$v1['name'],"SubCategory_id"=>$v1['category_id']);
$res = $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId,$v1['category_id']);
$iii = 0;
        foreach($res as $key=>$value) {
    $value = get_object_vars($value);
            $att=array("name", "description", "short_description");
                           $res2 = $proxy -> catalogProductInfo($sessionId,'13');
foreach($res2 as $key2=>$value2) {
                                var_dump("Name=>",$value2['name']);
                                $value2 = get_object_vars($value2);
                                $cat[$i]["SubCategory"][$ii]['Product_Details'][$iii]["Product_info"]= array("Product_id"=>$value['product_id'],"Product_Name" =>$value2["name"],"Product_sku"=>$value2["sku"],"Product_Categories"=>$value2['categories']); 
                            }
            $iii++;
        }
        $ii++;
    }
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($cat);
```

and the OutPut of the Following Code is given below-

```
[
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Mens Wear"
    }
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Womens Wear"
    }
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Mobile Phones"
    }
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Grocery"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SPICES & SEASONING",
                "SubCategory_id": 28
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "CEREALS & PULSES",
                "SubCategory_id": 29
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "RICE & FLOUR",
                "SubCategory_id": 30
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 13,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 24,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "OIL & GHEE",
                "SubCategory_id": 31
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SWEETNER & WHITNER",
                "SubCategory_id": 32
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "OTHERS",
                "SubCategory_id": 33
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Food"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DRIED READY MEALS",
                "SubCategory_id": 34
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SAUCES,SPREADS & PICKLES",
                "SubCategory_id": 35
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BAKERY",
                "SubCategory_id": 36
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "CHIPS & NAMKEENS",
                "SubCategory_id": 37
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "BEVERAGES"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "TEA & COFFEE",
                "SubCategory_id": 42
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "HEALTH & ENERGY DRINKS",
                "SubCategory_id": 43
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FRUIT DRINKS",
                "SubCategory_id": 44
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "PERSONAL CARE"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FACE CARE & LOTION",
                "SubCategory_id": 41
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FACE WASH & SCRUBS",
                "SubCategory_id": 45
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SHAMPOO & CONDITIONER",
                "SubCategory_id": 46
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 17,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "ORAL CARE",
                "SubCategory_id": 47
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BODY & HANDWASH",
                "SubCategory_id": 48
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "HAIR OIL & SERUM",
                "SubCategory_id": 49
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 16,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 21,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DEO,PERFUMES & TALC",
                "SubCategory_id": 50
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "HAIR STYLING CREAMS & GEL",
                "SubCategory_id": 51
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SHAVING NEEDS",
                "SubCategory_id": 52
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SHOE CARE",
                "SubCategory_id": 58
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "DETERGENT & TOILETRIES"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DETERGENT BAR & POWDER",
                "SubCategory_id": 53
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 14,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 15,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 20,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 22,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SANITARY&FLOOR CLEANERS",
                "SubCategory_id": 54
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FABRIC CARE",
                "SubCategory_id": 55
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DETERGENT BAR & POWDER",
                "SubCategory_id": 56
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DISHWASHER AGENTS",
                "SubCategory_id": 57
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Baby CARE"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY DIAPERS",
                "SubCategory_id": 59
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY CREAMS",
                "SubCategory_id": 60
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 18,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY SOAP",
                "SubCategory_id": 61
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY SHAMPOO",
                "SubCategory_id": 62
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY OIL",
                "SubCategory_id": 63
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY FOOD",
                "SubCategory_id": 64
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "OTHER PRODUCTS"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "REPELLENT",
                "SubCategory_id": 73
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "MEDICATIONS&TREATMENT",
                "SubCategory_id": 74
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 23,
                        "Product_Name": null,
                        "Product_sku": null,
                        "Product_Categories": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "WOMEN'S HYGIENE",
                "SubCategory_id": 75
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "CONDOMS",
                "SubCategory_id": 76
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SEXUAL WELLNESS",
                "SubCategory_id": 77
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FOIL PAPER & NAPKINS",
                "SubCategory_id": 78
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Why i am getting null values for product details.Tried everything but can't get those exact values.
If i passed a string (product_id) explicitly,i got correct output like

```
Input-  $res = $proxy -> catalogProductInfo($sessionId,'13');
$res = $proxy -> catalogProductInfo($sessionId,'13');
$res = get_object_vars($res);
echojson_encode(array("Product_Name"=>$res['name'],"Product_sku"=>$res['sku'],"Product_Categories"=>$res['categories']));
Output-
{"Product_Name":"AASHIRVAAD SELECT ATTA","Product_sku":"A00669","Product_Categories":["2","18","30"]}
```

Thanks

Comment: Waiting for reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just put catalogProductInfo function before 4th foreach loop and remove that foreach loop.Code is here

```
<?php
$base='yourhost';
$proxy = new SoapClient($base.'/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
if($sessionId = $proxy->login('user123', 'user123'))
{
 // echo "Login Success";
$functions = $proxy->__getFunctions ();
}
$allCategories = $proxy -> catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, 2);
$allCategories = get_object_vars($allCategories);
$i = 0;
foreach($allCategories['children'] as $k => $v ){
    $v=get_object_vars($v);
    $cat[$i]["RootCategory"] = array("Category" => $v['name']);
    $subCat = $proxy -> catalogCategoryTree($sessionId, $v['category_id']);
    $subCat = get_object_vars($subCat);
    $ii = 0;
    foreach($subCat['children'] as $k1=>$v1) {
$v1 = get_object_vars($v1);
 $cat[$i]["SubCategory"][$ii]['Subcatinfo']= array("SubCategory" =>$v1['name'],"SubCategory_id"=>$v1['category_id']);
        $res = $proxy -> catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId, $v1['category_id']);

        $iii = 0;
        foreach($res as $key=>$value) {
    $value = get_object_vars($value);
            $att=array("name", "description", "short_description");
                           $res2 = $proxy -> catalogProductInfo($sessionId,strval($value['product_id']));
            $res2=get_object_vars($res2);
            //echo "Name=".$res2['name'];
            $cat[$i]["SubCategory"][$ii]['Product_Details'][$iii]["Product_info"]= array("Product_id"=>$value['product_id'],"Product_Name" =>$res2["name"],
                "Product_sku"=>$res2["sku"],"Product_Categories"=>$res2['categories'],"Type"=>$res2['type'],"Description"=>$res2['description'],
                "Short-Description"=>$res2['short_description '],"status"=>$res2['status'],"Visibility"=>$res2['visibility'],"price"=>$res2['price'],
                "special-price"=>$res2['special_price']);

            $iii++;
        }
        $ii++;
    }
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($cat);
```

and the desired output is-

```
[
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Mens Wear"
    }
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Womens Wear"
    }
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Mobile Phones"
    }
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Grocery"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SPICES & SEASONING",
                "SubCategory_id": 28
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "CEREALS & PULSES",
                "SubCategory_id": 29
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "RICE & FLOUR",
                "SubCategory_id": 30
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 13,
                        "Product_Name": "AASHIRVAAD SELECT ATTA",
                        "Product_sku": "A00669",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "18",
                            "30"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "Aashirvaad Atta is made from the choicest grains - heavy on the palm, golden amber in colour and hard in bite. It is carefully ground using modern 'chakki - grinding' process for the perfect balance of colour, taste and nutrition which also ensures that Aashirvaad atta contains 0% Maida and is 100% Sampoorna Atta. The dough made from Aashirvaad Atta absorbs more water, hence rotis remain softer for longer.",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "60.0000",
                        "special-price": "0.0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 24,
                        "Product_Name": "AASHIRVAAD SELECT ATTA 5 Kg",
                        "Product_sku": "vfhbnvbh",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "18",
                            "30"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "AASHIRVAAD SELECT ATTA 5 KG\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "2",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "50.0000",
                        "special-price": null
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "OIL & GHEE",
                "SubCategory_id": 31
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SWEETNER & WHITNER",
                "SubCategory_id": 32
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "OTHERS",
                "SubCategory_id": 33
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Food"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DRIED READY MEALS",
                "SubCategory_id": 34
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SAUCES,SPREADS & PICKLES",
                "SubCategory_id": 35
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BAKERY",
                "SubCategory_id": 36
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "CHIPS & NAMKEENS",
                "SubCategory_id": 37
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "BEVERAGES"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "TEA & COFFEE",
                "SubCategory_id": 42
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "HEALTH & ENERGY DRINKS",
                "SubCategory_id": 43
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FRUIT DRINKS",
                "SubCategory_id": 44
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "PERSONAL CARE"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FACE CARE & LOTION",
                "SubCategory_id": 41
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FACE WASH & SCRUBS",
                "SubCategory_id": 45
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SHAMPOO & CONDITIONER",
                "SubCategory_id": 46
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 17,
                        "Product_Name": "TRESEMME CLIMATE CONTROL SHMPOO600ML",
                        "Product_sku": "A00173",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "22",
                            "46"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "TRESEMME CLIMATE CONTROL SHMPOO\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "345.0000",
                        "special-price": "335.0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "ORAL CARE",
                "SubCategory_id": 47
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BODY & HANDWASH",
                "SubCategory_id": 48
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "HAIR OIL & SERUM",
                "SubCategory_id": 49
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 16,
                        "Product_Name": "DABUR AMLA HAIR OIL 90ML",
                        "Product_sku": "A00240",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "22",
                            "49"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "DABUR AMLA HAIR OIL\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "42.0000",
                        "special-price": "41.0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 21,
                        "Product_Name": "DABUR AMLA HAIR OIL 275ML",
                        "Product_sku": "A00299",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "49"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "DABUR AMLA HAIR OIL 275ML\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "125.0000",
                        "special-price": "120.0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DEO,PERFUMES & TALC",
                "SubCategory_id": 50
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "HAIR STYLING CREAMS & GEL",
                "SubCategory_id": 51
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SHAVING NEEDS",
                "SubCategory_id": 52
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SHOE CARE",
                "SubCategory_id": 58
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "DETERGENT & TOILETRIES"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DETERGENT BAR & POWDER",
                "SubCategory_id": 53
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 14,
                        "Product_Name": "SURF EXCEL WSHG BAR 400 G",
                        "Product_sku": "A00179",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "24",
                            "53"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "SURF EXCEL WSHG BAR 400 G\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "46.0000",
                        "special-price": "45.0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 15,
                        "Product_Name": "RIN ADVANCED PWDR 1KG",
                        "Product_sku": "A00303",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "24",
                            "53"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "RIN ADVANCED PWDR 1KG\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "75.0000",
                        "special-price": "74.0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 20,
                        "Product_Name": "SURF EXCEL WASHING BAR 800 G",
                        "Product_sku": "A00300",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "53"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "SURF EXCEL WASHING BAR 800 G\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "88.0000",
                        "special-price": "87.0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 22,
                        "Product_Name": "RIN ADVANCED PWDR 1KG",
                        "Product_sku": "A0030",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "53"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "RIN ADVANCED DETERGENT POWDER\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "75.0000",
                        "special-price": "74.0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SANITARY&FLOOR CLEANERS",
                "SubCategory_id": 54
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FABRIC CARE",
                "SubCategory_id": 55
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DETERGENT BAR & POWDER",
                "SubCategory_id": 56
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "DISHWASHER AGENTS",
                "SubCategory_id": 57
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "Baby CARE"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY DIAPERS",
                "SubCategory_id": 59
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY CREAMS",
                "SubCategory_id": 60
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 18,
                        "Product_Name": "JOHNSON BABY MILK CREAM 50G",
                        "Product_sku": "A00187",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "26",
                            "60"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "JOHNSON BABY MILK CREAM\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "70.0000",
                        "special-price": "68.0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY SOAP",
                "SubCategory_id": 61
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY SHAMPOO",
                "SubCategory_id": 62
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY OIL",
                "SubCategory_id": 63
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "BABY FOOD",
                "SubCategory_id": 64
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "RootCategory": {
        "Category": "OTHER PRODUCTS"
    },
    "SubCategory": [
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "REPELLENT",
                "SubCategory_id": 73
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "MEDICATIONS&TREATMENT",
                "SubCategory_id": 74
            },
            "Product_Details": [
                {
                    "Product_info": {
                        "Product_id": 23,
                        "Product_Name": "VOLINI SPRAY 40 GM",
                        "Product_sku": "A00361",
                        "Product_Categories": [
                            "2",
                            "74"
                        ],
                        "Type": "simple",
                        "Description": "VOLINI SPRAY 40 GM\r\n",
                        "Short-Description": null,
                        "status": "1",
                        "Visibility": "4",
                        "price": "99.0000",
                        "special-price": "95.0000"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "WOMEN'S HYGIENE",
                "SubCategory_id": 75
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "CONDOMS",
                "SubCategory_id": 76
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "SEXUAL WELLNESS",
                "SubCategory_id": 77
            }
        },
        {
            "Subcatinfo": {
                "SubCategory": "FOIL PAPER & NAPKINS",
                "SubCategory_id": 78
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
It works for me.
```